# F# currying - calling with two parameters

Tags: f#, currying

I have problem, that can be reduced to following example:

```
let func a b c = printf "%s %s %s" a b c
let partial = func "a"

let something_that_returns_two_parameters = "b", "c" // what to write here?

something_that_returns_two_parameters |> partial // what to write here?
```

My expected result is func being called with "a" "b" "c". 
I can edit last two lines.
Is this achievable in some way?

Comment: `"b","c"` defines a tuple, not what the method expects

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I'm aware of that. Can the tuple be applied 'separately'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to apply the tuple using the `||>` operator:

```
something_that_returns_two_parameters ||> partial
```

This operator applies each component of the tuple to the function.

See [F# operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/index) for reference.

Comment: Thanks! Just out of my curiosity, how is the operator called?

Comment: I don't think it has a standard name, it's just the forward pipe but with two arguments. There is also a version with three.